# [ROS2] tf2 "authority undetectable" / "no authority available"

Tags: ros, ros2, tf2, joint-state-publisher, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm playing around with tf2 in ROS2 Foxy using a Gazebo simulated robot, and get warning messages regarding the tf2 "authority".

For instance, running `ros2 run tf2_ros tf2_monitor`, I can see that the static and dynamic transforms are being published by "`<no authority available>`", e.g.:

```
Frame: back_right_wheel_link, published by <no authority available>, Average Delay: 0.000709075, Max Delay: 0.0118647
Frame: base_link, published by <no authority available>, Average Delay: 1.62619e+09, Max Delay: 1.62619e+09
```

TF buffers also mention the undetectable Authority. E.g. RViz also gives TF related warnings mentioning the `Authority`

```
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame right_rocker_link at time 7.421000 according to authority Authority undetectable
```

I haven't found much in terms of documentation or search results referring to the "authority", so I was hoping someone could give some insight into what it is, how it is typically set, etc.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382377/%5Bros2%5D-tf2-%22authority-undetectable%22-/-%22no-authority-available%22/) by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1567 on 2021-07-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Took some digging, but the issues I was experiencing were due to the following reasons:

- Overlap between the joints being published by gazebo_ros_pkgs' joint_state_publisher and ros2_control's joint_state_broadcaster
- Issues with [`use_sim_time`](https://answers.ros.org/question/201948/tf_old_data-ignoring-data-from-the-past-for-frame-odom/) not being set on the `joint_state_broadcaster` using normal [launch file parameter inclusion](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/issues/325). The result was some joint transforms being published using the wall clock, and others being published using Gazebo's simulated clock. Setting `use_sim_time` in the yaml config file for each controller/broadcaster resolved this issue

But more to the point of my original question, the `authority` is meant to be the [source of the transformation information](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/bd125c5af32e2c63c70b7e0ba88e57094714b9b8/tf2/include/tf2/buffer_core.h#L114). Presumably this is meant to be the name of the node that is publishing the transformation (e.g. your joint_state_broadcaster).

The "Authority undetectable" message stems from the fact that, as of the time this question was written, extracting the transformation's source is [still a TODO](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/141e3cb732e5c4dba744abac381c8317ffb286f0/tf2_ros/src/transform_listener.cpp#L98-L99) in transform_listener.cpp and the authority is set to `"Authority undetectable"` by default.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2021-10-15**:
Hi, I'm also using Gazebo and I couldn't retrieve any name of tf publisher nodes. If I get your experience, you achieve to retrieve it ?